# Overwriting application.conf using Maven and generating jar file

Tags: scala, maven, jar, config

I have a Scala app (v2.13) created using Maven v3. My resources path is:

`src -> main -> resources -> application.conf and aplication.prod.conf`

When I generate the JAR file for production, I want to take configuration resources from `application.conf`, but being overwriten by `application.prod.conf`.

I can not found a solution for that, all founded examples are for Play framework or previous maven versions.

The JAR file is generated using `maven package` cmd.

application.prod.conf file

```
include "application.conf"

# override default (DEV) settings

http {
  host = "99.999.999.9"
  port = 1111
}
```

The following example doesn't works for me, because from `target` path I get only the JAR file to move it on production:

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <target>
                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.conf"/>
                    <copy file="src/main/resources/application.prod.conf"
                          tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.conf"/>
                 </target>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven has a concept of phases (we're talking about the phase `package` here to be precise) which are logical places in the life cycle where the plugins can be invoked. Some plugins, like the one that creates the jar, for example, are associated to phases automatically (out-of-the-box), others you define explicitly and associate with the phase (like `maven-antrun-plugin` which is executed during the phase `package` as you've showed in the code snippet).

With that in mind, Is it possible that the file is attempted to get copied **after** the jar was packaged, so that the `antrun` plugin is invoked after the artifacts were packaged into the jar?

If so, the easiest solution will be moving it to one phase before, for example `prepare-package`:

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>prepare-package</phase>  <!-- Note the change here -->
             <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <target>
                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.conf"/>
                    <copy file="src/main/resources/application.prod.conf"
                          tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.conf"/>
                 </target>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Assuming you have maven 3 (there is no maven version 4 yet so it might be a typo), the information about which phases are available in maven [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference)

Having said that, probably its not a good idea to "bake" the configuration file of production into the artifact, two issues here:

1. Your source code contains the information about production - hosts, ports, maybe even sensitive information like passwords or keys - this shouldn't really happen
2. From the point of view of build, your artifact is coupled to concrete environment, which is also considered a bad practice basically.

The techniques to resolve this are beyond the scope of the question but at least you've been warned :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. If I understand, you tell me to not store host, port, dbUser & pw in app configuration file. This is the easyest way to run app in production with a simple command line, because we don't have already implemented ci/cd. Then, I think I can  move all these data in a jenkins script file (or this will be the same as app config file?). Anyway, we use a vpn for connection to our apps, so I think (and I hope) is safe even with sensitive data in a config file.

Answer (score 2):

Few options here:

1. If your `application.prod.cont` is static and gets shipped with `jar`, why cant you have a logic in the code which loads appropriate app conf based on the environment app is getting executed
2. Is it a typesafe config, if so, while running in prod you can pass `-Dconfig.resource=/application.prod.conf` java command line argument
3. or `application.prod.conf` is not shipped with jar then you can pass `-Dconfig.file=/path/to/application.prod.conf`

Comment: thanks for your anwer. I checked it and is a right way to do that, but I choosed Mark's answer as solution because is more explicit. I voted up.